# Customise the Visual Studio colour scheme per solution

Tags: visual-studio-2013

Is it possible to customise Visual Studio's title background colour based on the solution loaded?

I end up needing to have multiple Visual Studio instances open with very similar content, so I'm ending up losing track of what I'm looking at.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think you can get different color schemes configured automatically and have it switch by what solution you load.

But you could try the VSCommands extension, they add something called [Solution Badges](http://vscommands.squaredinfinity.com/Features-SolutionBadges) that might make your life a bit easier.

Get the extension from the gallery at http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/c6d1c265-7007-405c-a68b-5606af238ece

Comment: I think that could be even better than what I was looking for, I'm installing it now!

Comment: The VS2015 version is here https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=SquaredInfinityJarekKardas.VSCommands14forVisualStudio2015

Comment: Project seems to be stalled.

Answer (score 8):

There is an extension called SolutionColor which is available from Tools -> Extension and Updates -> Online and search.

In later VS it is located under Externsions => Manage extensions

When installed, right click the Toolbar and add Solution Color.

Comment: Just installed it, a nifty little tool. Once installed it can be found under view -> tool bars > Solution Color.